# How to call a function from a function pointer of an instantiated object in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, pointer-to-member

I have two classes, `Sim` and `IElement`. The class `IElement` defines a function pointer, whereas the class `Sim` has a vector of `IElement` pointers. What is the correct way to call the pointed-to function from the function pointer defined in `IElement`, given that I have a vector of `IElement*`?

Or in another words, I have

```
std::vector<IElement*> nodes;
```

And I need to call a pointed-to function from `IElement`:

```
nodes[i]->*SetInput(); // ERROR: Identifier "SetInput" is undefined
```

I assume I'm having this error because `nodes` is a vector of pointers, and I am unaware of how to dereference `nodes[i]` before calling its pointed-to function.

Thank you for any advice.

A bit more detailed snippets of the code are given below.

The method of the `Sim` class where I am having the error `Undefined identifier` for the method of `IElement`

```
#include <vector>
#include "Elements.h" // defines class IElement in namespace Elements
void Sim::CreateNodes(int N) // this method belongs to the Sim class in namespace "Simulations"
{
    nodes = std::vector<Elements::IElement*>(N);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < N)
    {
        nodes[i] = new Elements::IElement(true); // for the sake of the example
        nodes[i]->*SetInput(); // ERROR: Identifier "SetInput" is undefined
        i++;
    }
}
```

whereas in the `Elements` namespace, I have the class `IElement` declaration

```
class IElement
{
public:
    typedef void(IElement::*SetInputFc_ptr)();
    IElement(bool); // normalizeInput
    ~IElement();
    SetInputFc_ptr SetInput;
};
```

and the class `IElement` implementation

```
IElement::IElement(bool normalizeInput)
{
    if (normalizeInput)
    {
        this->SetInput= &(this->SetInput_Sum);
    }
    else
    {
        this->SetInput= &(this->SetInput_Const);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to both get the `SetInput` member value from the `IElement` object, using a normal member operator, and then call the member function on the `IElement` object, using `->*`.  Assuming you want to use the same `IElement` for both:

```
(nodes[i]->*(nodes[i]->SetInput))();
```

Or perhaps rewrite the couple of statements as:

```
Elements::IElement* node = Elements::GetElement(i);
nodes[i] = node;
(node->*(node->SetInput))();
```

By the way, `&(this->SetInput_Sum)` is not an officially valid way to get a pointer to member.  If your compiler accepts it, it's allowing it as an extension.  The `IElement` constructor should be written:

```
IElement::IElement(bool normalizeInput)
{
    if (normalizeInput)
    {
        this->SetInput= &IElement::SetInput_Sum;
    }
    else
    {
        this->SetInput= &IElement::SetInput_Const;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the extra mistake... I had not tried to compile the full code by the time I posted the question, and the error I posted was reported by Visual Studio (configured to compile with Intel compiler)

Answer (score 1):

This also seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). C++ has classes that mean you can avoid the `if` in the first place by subclassing and having a normalized and non-normalized version of same. Override `SetInput` accordingly.

That plays out roughly like this:

```
class IElement
{
public:
    IElement();
    virtual ~IElement();

    virtual void SetInput();
};

class IElementNormalized : IElement {
    IElementNormalized();
    virtual ~IElementNormalized();

    virtual void SetInput();
};
```

Object-Oriented design principles generally steer towards using classes to do a lot of the work for you, avoiding the need for individual classes to differentiate like this.

You could always capture the boolean used on the constructor and just reference that as a property when performing whatever operations you need to, doing it procedurally within each function needing to know.

Comment: An excellent point, assuming `SetInput` doesn't need to change to a different function during any one object's lifetime.

Comment: @aschepler Exactly! Let the vtable do all the work for you.

Comment: In the real program, IElement is a primitive class as well, such that many other classes inherit from it; Thus it seems to me that having a virtual `SetInput` would force me to declare two of each derived classes as well, one implementing `IElement` and the other implementing `IElementNormalized`. I am not an expert in design patterns though :)

Comment: C++ supports multiple inheritance, so it's not always a big deal. You could also use a template class where the implementation of `SetInput` differs depending on parameters and you pass in a normalization class to use. It depends on how performance sensitive this code is. Something like `IElement<INormalizer> x` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of calling method through pointer.

```
#include <vector>

class IElement
{
    public:
        void action() {}
};

using MemberPtr = void (IElement::*)();    
MemberPtr Action = &IElement::action;

int main()
{
    std::vector<IElement*>  nodes{1, new IElement};

    (nodes[0]->*Action)();
    // Note the braces around the expression before the call.
    // This is because `()` binds tighter than `->*` so you need the
    // extra braces to force the `->*` to bind first so you can then call
    // the resulting method.

    //  nodes[0]->*Action();  // This will not compile.
}
```

Comment: maybe because I use `typedef` inside the `IElement` class, this fails with the same error in my case (reported by Visual Studio, I had not tried to compile)